# Can I sort my Steam games by installed size?

Tags: steam

Apparently my puny hard drive can't handle the awesomeness of Payday 2, XCOM: Enemy Unknown, and Fallout: New Vegas all being installed on my hard disk at the same time.

I spent all my money buying Payday, XCOM and New Vegas so now I can't afford a bigger hard drive.  I need to uninstall some of my old games to make room.

**Is there a way to sort my Steam games by size on disk?**  I would prefer to only remove one game rather than several.

Comment: Before you ask, it's 120 GB.

Comment: The 120gb is an ssd right? Don't you have another drive where you can install games on?

Comment: @Lyrion - Nope.  It's not an SSD, it's just a standard 120GB hard drive.  I have a *very* cheap gaming computer so that I can have a very nice work computer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to spend a little less money on your working computer and some more on your gaming computer? Well depending on your work ofcourse...

Comment: Can we change the accepted answer to this question? The UI has been updated, and a new answer explains how to do this with the new UI.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In the newer version of Steam, go to **LIBRARY**

and in the second block ("shelf") under "WHAT'S NEW", set dropdown to "ALL" and "SORT BY" "Size on Disk".

[image]

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer as this layout is now being used by the Steam Client

Comment: I agree with the above comment. But also, is there no way to show this in a list? Going through this view takes longer since the images are so large. I just got an SSD and want to move everything from C to it. Since I probably won't get a response soon, I'll just look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common`

Comment: @RubelliteFae see my new answer

Answer (score 88):

**Yes.** If you go to library and use 'list view' (accessible using the circled button) , then right click in the bar which says Games/Status/Metascore you can select the displayed columns. Click on 'Size on Disk' so that appears as a column, then click on the column header to sort.

[image: Steam menu bar]

If it defaults to showing them in descending order, another click will change the order to ascending.

Comment: Nice. That probably doesn't include savegames stored e.g. at `%appdata%`, right?

Comment: Additional Suggestion: http://windirstat.info/ - Windirstat is a great tool for hard drive useage. You can select a drive or a folder (in case there are other things on the drive that might be taking up space) and get stats and a visualization of what is taking up space. (Especially if you have "other" stuff on the drive in question)

Comment: Addition to additional suggestion: for Linux (and probably SteamOS) [baobab](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Baobab) (Gnome's disk usage analyzer) does very well

Comment: Thanks! This is very hard to find. I'll add that if you are sorting by something else (like categories) then the Size On Disk will not override that (you'll still get the games sorted in categories, then size). So you need to click the drop-down to the right of the search box and choose "Installed" (which will also filter out any non-installed games).

Comment: Disk Inventory X is the Mac OSX version of WinDirStat and his highly recommended for Mac users: http://www.derlien.com/

Comment: This appears to be out of date.

Answer (score 10):

In the current version of Steam (October 2021), go to *Settings*/*Preferences...* -> *Downloads* -> *STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS*

[image: Settings]

This will open the "Storage Manager" where you can select *Sort By: Size on Disk*

Here you can also conveniently remove games.

[image: Storage manager]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get your games lined up by size on **Windows** which I adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868264/du-in-powershell), and is a little technical, is thus:

Open PowerShell (windows key, search `powershell`) and run (copy+paste) these commands:

**1)**
`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\`  (or wherever your games are stored)

**2)**

```
function du($dir=".") {
gci . | 
  %{$f=$_; gci -r $_.FullName | 
    measure-object -property length -sum |
    select  @{Name="Name"; Expression={$f}}, 
            @{Name="Sum (GB)"; 
            Expression={"{0:N3}" -f ($_.sum / 1GB) }}, Sum } |
  sort Sum -desc |
  format-table -Property Name,"Sum (GB)", Sum -autosize
}
```

This makes a custom function that emulates Unix's [du](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html).

**3)** `du`

My output, for example:

```
Name                            Sum (GB)         Sum
----                            --------         ---
Total War THREE KINGDOMS        33.443   35909039516
PlanetSide 2                    14.001   15033674892
GarrysMod                       12.345   13255649379
Sid Meier's Civilization VI     10.941   11748131253
Cities_Skylines                 10.821   11618987046
Sid Meier's Civilization V      7.706     8274111473
Skyrim                          5.618     6031946296
Counter-Strike Source           4.311     4628808572
SpaceEngine                     4.060     4359200968
ProjectZomboid                  3.272     3513211040
Eve Online                      2.878     3090069433
Risk of Rain 2                  2.023     2172673698
Rollercoaster Tycoon 2          1.252     1344095911
MountBlade Warband              1.233     1324245692
Steamworks Shared               0.885      950038706
Stronghold                      0.834      895090145
Terraria                        0.274      293967879
Rust                            0.173      186144088
Dying Light                     0.127      135939819
Grand Theft Auto V              0.109      116674056
Realm Grinder                   0.044       47739977
Half-Life 2                     0.036       38305374
Counter-Strike Global Offensive 0.035       37479143
Left 4 Dead 2                   0.006        6825097
BorderlandsPreSequel            0.005        5884085
left 4 dead                     0.001        1075611
Unturned                        0.000         188449
Borderlands 2                   0.000         171267
Total War Rome II               0.000          83768
SharecareVR                     0.000           5939
The Walking Dead                0.000            957
The Witcher 3                   0.000              8
```

The directories at the bottom are nearly empty because I uninstalled the games and there are some residual files, or the bulk of the files are installed on another drive.

This is one of the many reasons that video games are the *only* reason I use Windows, but alas..